# Moodle - Olvide mi usuario o contraseña no funciona

Tags: smtp, moodle

Estoy administrando un sitio web moodle con un servidor dedicado de Godaddy y dentro de la aplicación configure correctamente el servidor SMTP para enviar correos, probé recuperar una contraseña y envió el link correctamente pero al día siguiente dejó de funcionar sin razón aparente.
El correo de prueba funciona con éxito igualmente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dejó de funcionar es que no envió más emails? El correo de prueba es de moodle? Sigue funcionando? Has visto algo en los logs de moodle?

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, lo solucione utilizando smtp de gmail, al parecer moodle no esta detectando los correos institucionales o con servidores smtp en especifico el mío de godaddy.

Comment: Significa que tu servicio de email (el que no funcionó) está bloqueando algo y no revisaste. Queda para cuando no quieras depender de gmail ;)

Comment: Gracias, si al parecer el smtp me lo bloquea y no me deja enviar, creo que gmail me lo detecta los correos desde allí como spam y por eso no recibo confirmación del correo.

Comment: Lo pongo aca porque se borró la otra pregunta fuera de tema. En la [pagina de instalación](https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/Installing_Moodle) estan los requisitos minimos de Moodle y en [recomendaciones de rendimiento](https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/Performance_recommendations) explica un poco como escalar Moodle para muchos usuarios (aunque las dos están en inglés). No sé mucho de Moodle o instalar paginas a gran escala asi que no puedo ser de más ayuda.

Comment: Gracias igualmente, es que revise esa documentación, pero es algo inespecífica, pero muchas gracias por las recomendaciones de rendimiento.